# Conditional probability $P(M(n)=X|M(2n)=X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I've got this problem related to conditional probability and the law of total probability.

A particle moves randomly around a network consisting of three sites. At each time $0,1,2,\dots$, its position is one of the points $X$, $Y$ or $Z$.
If the particle’s current position is X, then at the next step it stays at X with probability 1/2, and moves to Y with probability 1/2.
If the particle’s current position is Y , then at the next step it moves to X with probability 3/8, and moves to Z with probability 5/8.
Once the particle is at Z, it stays at Z for ever.
In all cases, the next step is made independently of the path by which the particle reached its current position.

At time 0 the particle is at position X.
Let $M(n)\in \{X, Y, Z\}$ denote the position of the particle at time n. Let $p(n) = P(M(n) = X)$, the probability that the particle is at position X at time n.

I need to find an expression for the following conditional probability:
$P(M(n)=X | M(2n)=X)$.

I have so far managed to find a recurrence relation for p(n):

$16p(n)=8p(n-1)+3p(n-2)$, and the initial conditions $p(0)=1$, $p(1)=1/2$, to give the solution:
$p(n)=(-1)^n (1/4)^{n+1}+(3/4)^{n+1}$.

However, I am not sure how to find an expression for the required probability. Any ideas?

Comment: Please type you equations using mathjax. I started it for you. Go into your question and add $ signs around your formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too get $p(n)=(3^{n+1}+(-1)^n)/4^{n+1}$

> However, I am not sure how to find an expression for the required probability. Any ideas?

Use Bayes' Rule.
Let $p(s\mid t):=\mathsf P(M(s)=X\mid M(t)=X)$ .  $$p(n\mid 2n)=\dfrac{p(2n\mid n)~p(n)}{p(2n)}$$

Also consider that $p(n)$ is the probability that the position is a $X$ after $n$ time units passes from initially being at position $X$ (ie at time $0$), while $p(2n\mid n)$ is the probability that the position is at $X$ after $n$ time units passes from being at position $X$ at time $n$.    So...